# Erro warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'float *', Linguagem C

Tags: c

Olá, fiz esse programa para mostrar a media entre 2 números e mostrar se o aluno foi aprovado ou não, porém o resultado não esta dando certo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  float primeiraNota, segundaNota, media;

     printf("Digite a primeira nota: ");
       scanf("%f", & primeiraNota);
     printf("Digite a segunda nota: ");
       scanf("%f", & segundaNota);

    media = (primeiraNota + segundaNota)/ 2;

    if (media > 6)
      printf(" O aluno esta aprovado com a media = %f", &media);

      else
        printf(" O aluno esta reprovado com a media = %f", &media);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função [`printf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) está recebendo `%f` na [string de formatação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string), e isso requer uma variável do tipo `double` ou `float` na lista de formatação.

O *warning* está acontecendo pois você está passando o **endereço da variável** `media` (ou `float*`) na lista de formatação e não o seu conteúdo.

O correto seria:

```
if (media > 6)
    printf(" O aluno esta aprovado com a media = %f", media);
else
    printf(" O aluno esta reprovado com a media = %f", media);
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!